# $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Let $R = \Z[x]$ and $I = (x)$, $J = (x, 7)$. Find $\operatorname{Tor}_i(R/I, R/J)$.

Tags: solution-verification, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Let $R = \Z[x]$ and $I = (x)$, $J = (x, 7)$. The problem is to find $\operatorname{Tor}_i(R/I, R/J)$. This came up in studying for quals. I think I solved this problem, but I wanted to make sure I did it correctly.

Consider the exact sequence $$0 \to R \to R \to R/I \to 0$$ where the first map is multiplication by $x$ and the second is the quotient map. This is a projective resolution of $R/I$ so $\operatorname{Tor}_i(R/I, R/J)$ is the $i$th homology of the complex $$0 \to R \otimes R/J \to R \otimes R/J \to 0.$$ We can identify $R \otimes R/J$ with $R/J = \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ and under this identification the map $R \otimes R/J \to R \otimes R/J $ is the zero map. As such, the homology are $$\operatorname{Tor}_i(R/I, R/J) = \begin{cases}
 \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z} & i = 0, 1\\
 0 & i \geq 2.
\end{cases}$$

Is this correct? This is a quals problem so the above solution feels too good to be true.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks correct to me.